# 'Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined' when loading typedarray module

Tags: requirejs, polyfills, module.exports

I am trying to load the **typedarray** polyfill module:

https://github.com/substack/typedarray

in my app, like this (requireJS):

```
define(['typedarray'], function (ta) {
    ..

    var Uint8Array = ta.Uint8Array;
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    ..
});
```

The app compiles without problems but at runtime I get:

index.js:264 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Which is caused by this line in the polyfill's index.js:

```
exports.ArrayBuffer = exports.ArrayBuffer || ArrayBuffer;
```

How do I fix this? Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My bad! I used the wrong version. When using the compiled version for use in browsers it works. Although the polyfill doesn't work with the Blob object which was the my main purpose :-(